# Donet build (CLI) does not restore packages of framework 4.8

Tags: .net, build, .net-4.8

I`m doing an script to automate builds, but I encounter this problem: the command dotnet build does not restore the nuget package and I run into a error:
[it does not restore packages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QM1iJ.png)

even when a try a "dotnet restore" still says there are no package to restore...

the build works fine using visual studio I also have tried to do the build using "msbuild.exe" inside the visualstudio specific folder but still getting the same results.

Upgrade the projects that are in framework inst a option.

You have any workaround for this situation?

Comment: is this using new-style SDK projects and `<ProjectReference ...>` for Newtonsoft.Json? or is it packages.config based?

Comment: packages.config

Comment: right; so ... you'd probably have to use either MSBuild, or explicit nuget package restore; this is *exactly why SDK-style projects exist*; I strongly suggest migrating to an SDK-style project if at all possible (which is usually pretty easy except for ASP.NET web sites)